# Simulating a non-local request in Rails/RSpec request testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd like to block off access to the application to all non-local requesters (my application's actual functionality in practice is more sophisticated, but figuring out how to do this will solve my specific issue). How would I go about testing this with request tests in RSpec?

In `spec/requests/gatekeeper_spec.rb`

```
describe "A local request to the site root" do
  before :each do
    get root_path
  end
  it "should not allow access" do
    response.status.should be(401)
  end
end

describe "An external (terminology?) request to the site root" do
  before :all do
    # TODO: make request remote
  end
  before :each do
    get root_path
  end
  it "should allow access" do
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

How should I implement the `# TODO` line? I've looked into mocks and think that rigging `request.remote_ip` may be appropriate, but I'm not certain exactly how such a mock is implemented.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby on Rails, but should 'it "should [not] allow access" be " **if** ..."?

Comment: @Hello71: No worries. RSpec is funky; `it` is correct. It's part of this whole readability trend going on in the Ruby world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, test requests have a remote address of "0.0.0.0", so they would normally be considered remote and you'd want to stub the local requests, not the other way around.

I think this should work for controller specs -- not sure about request specs:

```
request.stub(:local?) { true }
```

Comment: The request object appears to be non-existent up until the point the request is made via `get`. I do suppose that extending that function is the best way out of this conundrum.

Comment: Hmm, looks like request specs are different. You might also try `get root_path, nil, "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"` to simulate localhost.

Comment: The stubbing idea is good, and I used it effectively in my controller specs. I implemented the "access checker" as a `before_filter`, and stubbed the corresponding filter to just return `true` instead of redirecting. Controller specs allowed me to access the controller via a local variable `controller`. As for request specs, I couldn't get it to work out, but the function has since changed, so hopefully, this gap will be ignored, at least until Rails Guides fills in that detail.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but *should* work in Rails 2.3.x and 3.0:

```
before :each do
  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
  end
end

after :each do
  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Rails 4** you can do it with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, allow_rescue: true) do
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.stub(:show_exceptions) { true }
    Rails.application.config.stub(:consider_all_requests_local) { false }
  end
end
```

And then in your test file:

```
describe "A test" do
  it "renders custom error pages", :allow_rescue => true do
    # ...
  end
end
```

The name `:allow_rescue` is taken from a `ActionController::Base.allow_rescue` configuration which exists in **Rails 3**, and there the RSpec configuration would be:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, allow_rescue: true) do
    ActionController::Base.stub(:allow_rescue) { true }
  end
end
```